# How to finger paint on Surface View In Android?

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview, paint

How to perform finger paint operation on surface view in android. I want draw on surface view as well as play video on that surface view is it possible in android please help me thanks.

Comment: you can make a trick like place a another view which has overloaded its "onDraw" method. You can find Finger Paint in API demos directory of Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

**You have a good example in API Demo: FingerPaint**

you can find it in the sample of your android sdk:
C:\ANDROID-SDK\samples\android17\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics